# Why does Code Analysis tell me, "Do not dispose objects multiple times" here:

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, filestream, dispose, binaryreader

On this code:

```
public static string Base64FromFileName(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
        long numBytes = fInfo.Length;
        FileStream fStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fStream);
        byte[] bdata = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);
        br.Close();
        fStream.Close();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(bdata);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

...I get, courtesy of Visual Studio's Code Analysis tool, the warning, "*Do not dispose objects multiple times...To avoid generating a System.ObjectDisposedException you should not call Dispose more than one time on an object*" on the "fStream.Close();" line.

Why? Is fStream disposed in the line above, where the BinaryReader is closed?

Wouldn't I be better off refactoring it like this anyway:

```
. . .
using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))   
{
    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fStream)) 
    {
        byte[] bdata = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);
    } //br.Close();
} //fStream.Close();
. . .
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`BinaryReader.Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) also closes the underlying stream, so this would indeed cause the stream to be disposed of twice. But that's not a real problem, disposing twice doesn't hurt.

You could write this much better as

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (var br = new BinaryReader(fs, new UTF8Encoding(), true))
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes));
}
```

This is the bomb-proof version:

- Anything that is successfully constructed is guaranteed to be disposed
- You won't dispose of the stream twice because the boolean `leaveOpen` argument on the `BinaryReader` constructor ensures that disposing (closing) it won't also close the stream

Answer (score 3):

Code Analysis is right; Code Analysis is wrong.

Yes, you're closing the FileStream twice.  This is harmless.  So is disposing it twice.  Multiple disposal happens.  It is the responsibility of the developer of a disposable component to handle multiple disposal properly and without throwing exceptions<sup>1</sup>.

However, while calling `Dispose()` on a disposed `FileStream` is a no-op by convention, the same isn't true of your code, which calls `Close()` on a disposed stream.  Don't do that.

Your suggested fix with the nested using is fine.

---

<sup>1</sup> [The contract for `IDisposable.Dispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) requires:

> If an object's `Dispose` method is called more than once, the object must ignore all calls after the first one. The object must not throw an exception if its `Dispose` method is called multiple times. Instance methods other than `Dispose` can throw an `ObjectDisposedException` when resources are already disposed.

The formal term for this behavior is *idempotence*.